# Hot to set correct Margin/Padding with Bootstrap using Container and Columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4.1, I have spend hours to simply align some columns within a container. But I cannot seem to get the margins and paddings right:

On large screens I want a 2x3 grid, with items boxed and a "frame" around all of the items. But the code posted below, however creates a huge gap (assumingly 2x 15px) between the two columns. How can I get rid of that space?!
Neither editing padding nor margins work.

See code snippet below:

```css
.test-container{
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item{
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.row{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid border-top bg-white shadow">
        <div class="col-sm-9 test-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">Select Unit</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">Unit 1 / Unit 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">Input:</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">Value_Input</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">Output</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item">The result is...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There must be a simple solution - but I have obviously no clue. Help is much appreciated.

*** EDIT ***
Just saw, that the code-snipped generates a 1x6 column. Obviously that is the final result I want on small screens. On large screens however I would like that 2x3 grid with no gap in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is fine. Columns in bootstrap have padding on the left and right of 15px by default and rows have padding on the left and right of -15px to counter this on the edge of the row. To get the result you desire, you need the following css:

```
.row{
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This removes the padding on the columns in order to get rid of the gap between the columns and instead puts padding of 15px on each row in order to squeeze the columns into the test container that you made.

Comment: Jeez - I knew the solution would be simple, yet I couldn't find the answer. Thanks - works like a charm!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.